# Concurrently updating a field with READ_COMMITED

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level

Assume we have the following row in a table already:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, amount) VALUES (1, 0);
```

Having the following queries running at the same time with **READ_COMMITED**:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, amount) VALUES (1, 0)
ON CONFLICT DO
  UPDATE some_table SET amount=amount+100 WHERE id=1;
```

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, amount) VALUES (1, 0)
ON CONFLICT DO
  UPDATE some_table SET amount=amount-50 WHERE id=1;
```

Can they run into race condition with resulting *amount = 100* or *amount = -50* if they both read initial (committed) amount=0 and one transaction overwrite the result of another one?

If yes, can it be fixed by:

1. switching to REPEATABLE_READ ?
2. using "FOR UPDATE" like this

```
WITH updating as (
    SELECT id, amount FROM some_table FOR UPDATE
)
INSERT INTO some_table (id, amount) VALUES (1, 0)
ON CONFLICT DO
  UPDATE some_table t SET t.amount=updating.amount+100 WHERE t.id=updating.id;
```

```
WITH updating as (
    SELECT id, amount FROM some_table FOR UPDATE
)
INSERT INTO some_table (id, amount) VALUES (1, 0)
ON CONFLICT DO
  UPDATE some_table t SET t.amount=updating.amount-50 WHERE t.id=updating.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` does not suffer from race conditions. One of the `UPDATE`s will lock the row first, and the other has to wait, but no matter what the order is, in the end the amount will be 50 more than in the beginning.

Note that `WHERE id = 1` is unnecessary, since the `UPDATE` will only affect the one row that conflicts with the `INSERT` anyway.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
I am referring to this part of the query:
UPDATE some_table SET amount=amount-50 WHERE id=1;

Under the hood it should read "amount" first to update it. Is the row locked before or after reading this value? 
If it is locked after reading, it can be affected by race condition.

Comment: The row is read again after the lock is obtained, so nothing can happen. The keyword for that in PostgreSQL  is "EvalPlanQual", you can search for that.